# Does $\sin^{-1}$ abide with the trig exponent notation?

Tags: trigonometry, pi

So I know that the difference between "$\sin^a$" and "$\sin^a$" is that "$\sin^a$" means "$(\sin)^a$" and "$\sin^a$" means "$\sin(^a)$", but does this work for -1? I know notation for the inverse of "$\sin$" is "$\sin^{-1}$", but this would mean "$(\sin)^{-1}$", which is not true. For example, "$\sin^{-1}1$" is "$\frac{\pi}{2}$" but "$\left(\sin\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{-1}$" is not the same. (In conclusion, "$\sin^{-1}$" is not the same as "$(\sin)^{-1}$".) Why not?

Comment: This is an inconsistency in common mathematical notation. This is because you very infrequently need $(\sin x)^{-1},$ while often need $\arcsin x.$ Even weirder, there are cases where $T^2(x)=T(T(x)).$ You just need to evaluate in context.

Comment: It is an unfortunate fact that $\sin^{-1}(x)$ is often used to represnt the *inverse sine function* (the function which, when given a number $x$ between $-1$ and $1$, will tell you the angle $\theta$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq \theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$, such that $\sin(\theta)=x$). Yes, it clashes with the usual notation that says that $\sin^n(x)$ means $(\sin x)^n$... as long as $n\neq -1$. I prefer to use $\arcsin(x)$ for the inverse sine function for that reason, but unfortunately I did not create this part of the world. It is inconsistent usage that you have to get used to.

Comment: Oh, phew. That's a relief, I thought I was crazy but it turns out it's just a problem with mathematical notation . I was always confused as to why $f^{-1}\left(x\right)$ meant the  inverse of $f\left(x\right)$. Thanks for clearing that up @ThomasAndrews @ArturoMagidin!

Comment: The weird thing is that $\arcsin$ is not really an inverse function, because $\sin$ is not $1-1.$ It is a "one-sided inverse." So $\arcsin,$ and related one-sided inverse functions $\arccos, \arctan, \dots$ really shouldn't be written as inverse functions.

Comment: @thomasandrews It's the inverse function of the restricted sine function.

Comment: Which is to say, a one-sided inverse. @ArturoMagidin Whenever there is one-sided inverse, it is also an inverse of the function on some restricted domain.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The inverse sine predates the "extended sine" defined at all real numbers. It is really a problem of notions expanding with nomenclature sticking to its original meaning.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same with every other function. $f^{-1}(x)$ means the inverse of $f$, and $f^n(x)$ means $(f(x))^n$ for all $n \neq 0$. It's the most despised notation in math.